# cisco static router issue

Tags: cisco, ip-routing

I have emulated some routers under GNS. The problem is the following:
The first router has (R1)192.168.1.1 ip address, the second router(R2) has 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.2.1 ip address and the third (R3) 192.168.2.2 and 192.168.3.1

The problem is that I have added a static route on first router, command is

ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.2 (R1)

ip routing(R2)

I can ping 192.168.2.1 from the first router, but I can not ping the third router, 192.168.2.2 , but i can ping this ip address from R2. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R3 doesn't know the Route to 192.168.1.0/24. you had to route 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.2.1 on R3